# Angular orderBy filter '.' predicate expression reverses array in angular v1.0.7

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

In angular.js 1.0.7 orderBy filter used with predicate string '.' reverses the array order.

For example:

```
$filter('orderBy')(['a','b','c'], '.'); // -> ['c', 'b', 'a'].
```

How one can explain the logic of the transformation?

**Upd.** answer already found by myself below.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what your question is... You are reversing it. I don't think `orderBy:.` does anything.

Comment: It seems you don't understand what the second parameter of the [`orderBy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filter do.

Comment: @Blackhole it is a expression that can be in form of a function, array or a string, in our case its a string, and I cant get the logic why it reverses the whole array?

Comment: @ShanRobertson Ill try from another angle, if you use `orderBy:<anything>:<anything>` you get the straight sorting BUT if you use `orderBy:'.':<whatever>` you get always strict OPPOSITE sorting. And I ask WTF?

Comment: This parameter, in its string form, is not intended to be use with array of primitives, but with array of objects. It is pretty normal that its behaviour is undefined then.

Comment: @Blackhole I just faced this example from angular fundamentals tutorial from wintellect.com. And there they had such an example where they used this '.'. So it exploded my mind, but later on it turned out that they were using angular version 1.0.7. And In Angular 1.2.* this behaviour was changed but nevertheless the question hung in the air.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a sane explanation to my question, which was pretty simple, why this awkward behavior happens, not how it's meant or supposed to be written, or kinda things. I just debugged the source code calls in dev tools withing angular step by step and it turns out to be this:

[image: Using '.' as a predicate in orderBy filter]

So it turns out that due to specificity of parsing mechanism in angular, '.' is eventually considered to be in this case a NaN and inside the sorting function of an array the last `return v1 < v2 ? -1 : 1;` defaults to false and we get 'return 1' which reverses our array order constantly.

You can yourself try `[1,2,3].sort(function(a, b){return 1;})`, the output will be `[3,2,1]`.

Bingo.

**Upd:** in current version of angular there is a correctly thrown error on such behavior:

`Error: $parse:syntax : Token '.' not a primary expression at column 1 of the expression [.] starting at [].`

Answer (score 3):

I cannot replicate using AngularJS 1.2.16. With a simple app the `orderBy` makes no modification to the input set:

```
Normal Order

a
b
c
d
e

Reverse Order

a
b
c
d
e
```

**PLUNKER EXAMPLE: http://embed.plnkr.co/jn8PHVrgUHqAYjApWMKd**

Note that the controller also includes a commented statement that changes the order of `$scope.abc` to not follow natural ordering. Even with this change, there's no effect on the output.

For more info you can look through the source of `orderBy` too: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/orderBy.js#L78

Answer (score 0):

playing around a little

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in abc | orderBy:'.'">{{i}}</li>

</ul>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in abc | orderBy">{{i}}</li>
</ul>
```

this does the trick, it has something to do with the expression and the fact that the array has primitive values. not sure why